# Configure Geronimos MDB InstanceLimit

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, geronimo

I'm not able to configure Geronimo/ActiveMQ so that more then 10 Messages get processed at once.

I tried the suggestions from this [mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/geronimo-user/200807.mbox/%3Cadd18bc80807171044u57cf26cfq467cf3eb29e7084b@mail.gmail.com%3E),
but setting the `maxSessions` to something higher than 10 doesn't have any effect. Setting it to something lower than that has an effect though...

Also I'tried to set the `InstanceLimit` by setting:

```
<module name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car">
    <gbean name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car?ServiceModule=org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car,j2eeType=GBean,name=CustomPropertiesGBean" 
           gbeanInfo="org.apache.geronimo.system.properties.SystemProperties">
        <attribute name="systemProperties">Default\ MDB\ Container.InstanceLimit=50</attribute>
    </gbean>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I got it! Here is a lengthy explanation, which hopefully will help someone too.

After tinkering around with [these examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC22/jms-application-with-message-driven-bean.html) I figured out that the activation parameters of ActiveMQ doesnt limit the upper bound, we can reduce the parallel instance though:

```
<activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
<activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property-name>maxSessions</activation-config-property-name>
    <activation-config-property-value>3</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
<activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property-name>maxMessagesPerSessions</activation-config-property-name>
    <activation-config-property-value>2</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

So I decided to go down the road of OpenSource! After attaching all needed source code of the involved components:

- Geronimo
- ActiveMQ
- OpenEJB

and going up the stacktrace I figured out, that the InstanceLimit is a GBean Property which is explicitly queried. Its default value is 10, which is hardcoded in Geronimo. By tweeking this value in the debugger I got the wished results!

But setting the InstanceLimit was also suggested in the [mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/geronimo-user/200807.mbox/%3Cadd18bc80807171044u57cf26cfq467cf3eb29e7084b@mail.gmail.com%3E) which suggested to add this to Geronimos config.xml

```
<module name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car">
    <gbean name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car?ServiceModule=org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.1.4/car,j2eeType=GBean,name=CustomPropertiesGBean" 
           gbeanInfo="org.apache.geronimo.system.properties.SystemProperties">
        <attribute name="systemProperties">Default\ MDB\ Container.InstanceLimit=50</attribute>
     </gbean>
</module>
```

(Of course with the correct version numbers)
But this doesn't had any effect. After carefully rereading this [hint](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/geronimo-user/200803.mbox/%3C466797bd0803231115p7c3d15bfhb37712c58fc984c7@mail.gmail.com%3E):

> Try setting the InstanceLimit property of the MdbContainer to 0 so that the no of instances created matches the no of AMQ sessions available. For setting this you need to set this as a system property.The property should be containerId.InstanceLimit where containerId is of the format

`<artifactId>.<Resource Group Name>-<listener interface>`

> eg: org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/2.2-SNAPSHOT/car.ActiveMQ RA-javax.jms.MessageListener

- `<artifactId>` = artifactId of the jms RA
- `<Resource Group Name>` - The resource Group name u gave while creating the RA
- `<listener interface>` - javax.jms.MessageListener in this case

and examining Geronimos code and runtime state I figured out it was looking for the InstanceLimit in `org.apache.geronimo.openejb.OpenEjbSystemGBean` line 309, with a destinct ID which was in the example project:

org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/2.2.1/car.ActiveMQ RA-javax.jms.MessageListener

Equiped with this information i gave this a try:

```
<module name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.2.1/car">
    <gbean name="org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.2.1/car?ServiceModule=org.apache.geronimo.configs/j2ee-server/2.2.1/car,j2eeType=GBean,name=CustomPropertiesGBean" 
               gbeanInfo="org.apache.geronimo.system.properties.SystemProperties">
        <attribute name="systemProperties">org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/2.2.1/car.ActiveMQ\ RA-javax.jms.MessageListener.InstanceLimit=50</attribute>
    </gbean>
</module>
```

and it worked! Whereby I got the used ID from the debugging session... Now we can set InstanceLimit=0 and can configured the parallel working MDB by the `maxSessions` property of ActiveMQ!